# Notification on child added/modified

Tags: android, notifications, background-service

How do i show  a notification in my app when a child is added/modified in firebase database ? I am using android studio. I have seen a lot of answers to use FCM or GCM .
But is there a way that i can use background service (which doesn't terminate on app termination) to check if there is a child is added/modified and create a local notification?

Answer (score 0):

You could Use google FCM data notification. 
check out the docs here[Firebase Cloud Messaging Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive?authuser=0)

Comment: Can you share some links of tutorials?